# How can I post my data onto the server?

Tags: c#

I am developing wp8 app. My question is that, The app is getting an error when I click on the registration button and the following exception occurred and the code is not going below string post data

An exception of type `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` occurred in **System.Windows.ni.dll** but was not handled in user code

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continue

```
namespace docapp
{
    public partial class registration : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public static string DeviceIDAsString;
        public registration()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            //selction.Items.Add("india");
            //selction.Items.Add("pakistan");
            //selction.Items.Add("china");
            //selction.Items.Add("USA");
            String[] name = { "india", "china", "pakistan" };
            String[] uname = { "Delhi", "Bijing", "Karachi" };
            String[] university = { "AIIMS", "MDU", "PGI" };
            String[] yeardate = { "2011", "2012", "2013" };
 string[] question = { "what is your pet name", "what is your childhood name", "what is your mother name" };
            this.country.ItemsSource = name;
            this.city.ItemsSource = uname;
            this.university.ItemsSource = university;
            this.year.ItemsSource = yeardate;
            this.question.ItemsSource = question;
              }

        private void Image_Tap_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {

            if (txtusername.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("enter the name");
            }
            else if (txtid.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("enter valid id");
            }
            else if (txtpassword.Password == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("enter the password");
            }
            else if (txtconfirm.Password == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("enter the same password again ");
            }
            else if (txtemail.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("enter the valid email id ");
            }
            else if (txtmobileno.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("enter the valid 10 digit mobile no ");
            }


            if (txtpassword.Password != txtconfirm.Password)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("password doesnot match please enter same password");
            }



            SendPost();
            //getDeviceId();


        }
        //private static String getDeviceId()
        //{
        //    //byte[] id = (byte[])Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceUniqueId");
        //    //return BitConverter.ToString(id).Replace("-", string.Empty);
        //    // get the unique device id for the publisher per device

        //}

        void SendPost()
        {


            byte[] myDeviceID = (byte[])Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceUniqueId");

             DeviceIDAsString = Convert.ToBase64String(myDeviceID); 

            Uri url = new Uri(" http://www.mobileoid2.co/docbase/index.php?methodname=createuser");

            // Create the web request object 
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Method = "POST";

            webRequest.Headers["username"] = txtusername.Text;
            webRequest.Headers["userid"] = txtid.Text;
            webRequest.Headers["password"] = txtpassword.Password;
            webRequest.Headers["confirmpaswword"] = txtconfirm.Password;
            webRequest.Headers["email"] = txtemail.Text;
            webRequest.Headers["mobileno"] = txtmobileno.Text;
            webRequest.Headers["country"] = country.SelectedItem.ToString();
            webRequest.Headers["city"] = city.SelectedItem.ToString();
            webRequest.Headers["university"] = university.SelectedItem.ToString();
            webRequest.Headers["year"] = year.SelectedItem.ToString();
            webRequest.Headers["question"] = question.SelectedItem.ToString();
            webRequest.Headers["uniqueid"] = DeviceIDAsString;
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/json;charset=utf-8";
            //"text/json";// 
            // Start the request 
            webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), webRequest);
        }
        void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {


            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
            // End the stream request operation 
            Stream postStream = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);



            string postData = "username" + txtusername.Text + ".userid" + txtid.Text + "." + ".password" + txtpassword.Password + "." + ".confirmpassword" + txtconfirm.Password + "." + ".email" + txtemail.Text + "." + ".mobileno" + txtmobileno.Text + "." + "." + ".country" + country.SelectedItem.ToString() + "." + "." + ".city" + city.SelectedItem.ToString() + "." + "." + ".university" + university.SelectedItem.ToString() + "." + "." + ".year" + year.SelectedItem.ToString() + "." + ".question" + question.SelectedItem.ToString() + "." + ".uniqueid" + DeviceIDAsString +".";
            var input = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postData);
             byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);

            // Add the post data to the web request 
            postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            postStream.Close();

            // Start the web request 
            webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), webRequest);
        }
        void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
                HttpWebResponse response;

                // End the get response operation 
                response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
                Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
                var Response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                //outputbox.Text = Response.ToString(); 
                streamResponse.Close();
                streamReader.Close();
                response.Close();

            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                // Error treatment 
                // ... 
            }
        }



        private void Image_Tap_2(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/docapp;component/login.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Please, format your code snippet correctly

Comment: "UnauthorizedAccessException" says it all, something in the OS (or on the server side) is not allowing you to post that data. First step is to find out which bit is refusing you - try it in the debugger to see, or add a load of logging.

Comment: the error is coming in string post data .

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but this error is generally thrown when the access is not allowed. Maybe the credentials you are trying to use are not allowed!

The issue is that the OS is denying the request due to I/O error, where the credentials are required, or you either don't have permission to read/write there, or the server needs a username/password match to allow you. Something like that. Try catching it using

```
try {
  // code here to try..
} catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException e) {
  // error e.Message
}
```

Here is a Remark from the MSDN blog post:

> An UnauthorizedAccessException exception is typically thrown by a method that wraps a Windows API call. To find the reasons for the exception, examine the text of the exception object's [Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.message%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property.

For More: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: the code deos not goes below string post data ?can you suggest why so

Comment: @rozy, yes, because the exception was caught at that line below it. The line at the string postdata was executed and the next line was caught into error. Thus throwing an exception...

Comment: any solution of this @afzaal

Comment: You need to test the API and its usage! I think, you will get a positive way of doing your project. You will get the best answer (well not the perfect answer, but the correct way of doing this) at http://msdn.microsoft.com